# slick schema extension with activeslick

Tags: slick

I have defined Person and Org (organization) schemas as

```
  trait Schema { this: Tables with TableQueries with Profile =>

  import jdbcDriver.simple._

    class PersonsTable(tag: Tag) extends EntityTable[Player](tag, "PERSON") {   def id = column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
          def dateCreated = column[Date]("DATE_CREATED")
          def firstName = column[String]("FIRST_NAME")
          def lastName = column[String]("LAST_NAME")}

      class OrgTable(tag: Tag) extends EntityTable[Player](tag, "ORG") {
          def id = column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
          def dateCreated = column[Date]("DATE_CREATED")
          def  = column[String]("NAME")
      }
  }
```

I soon realized that the schemas shared common fields like id (primary key) and dateCreated. So, I grouped them together so I don't have to repeat them,

```
  trait Schema { this: Tables with TableQueries with Profile =>

  import jdbcDriver.simple._

    class PersonsTable(tag: Tag) extends EntityTable[Player](tag, "PERSON") with CommonSchema#CommonFields {    def firstName = column[String]("FIRST_NAME")
          def lastName = column[String]("LAST_NAME")}

      class OrgTable(tag: Tag) extends EntityTable[Player](tag, "ORG") with CommonSchema#CommonFields {
          def  = column[String]("NAME")
      }
  }

  trait CommonSchema { this: Tables with TableQueries with Profile =>

      import jdbcDriver.simple._

      trait CommonFields{this: Table[_] =>
          def id = column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
          def dateCreated = column[Date]("DATE_CREATED")
      }
  }
```

I could not get this to compile. The compiler complained "CommonSchema is not a legal prefix for a constructor". How do I get it to work? I am using  ActiveSlick with this setup and I am using a generic jdbcDriver for these classes as a place holder until the final moment when I run this classes with a specific Slick driver i.e. `scala.slick.driver.H2Driver.simple._`. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the not extend part. I general be aware that abstractions like this require advanced Scala knowledge.

Comment: I could do the same for domain classes (like Person and Org) where the common properties are abstracted into another class. in this case I choose not to do it for simplicity (or could be a bad idea altogether). This is what my "not" refers to.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand your question.

Comment: I have added more details to my question